# how to pass associative array to Chart.js to produce bar plot

Tags: php, chart.js

I have a PHP array of objects, each object holds an associative array $key=>$value... each object holds info like:

```
object1: bread=>5, juice=>3
object2: bread=>3, meat=>4
```

this is the structure of each object:

```
class MyObject {

    var $id = 0;
    var $food = array();

    public function setid($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function getid() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setfood($key, $val) {
        $this->food[$key] = $val;
    }

    public function getfood($key) {
        return $this->food[$key];
    }
}
```

I am using Chart.js to plot, and I am trying to figure out how to build a bar plot that shows, for each object I have, bars corresponding to the associative array values.

The point is that I don't know how many keys there are in the associative arrays, so it's difficult for me to understand how to prepare the datasets. If I know the number of bars before, I can do something like:

```
data: {
    labels: somelabels,
    datasets:[{
          label: 'Bread',
        data: breadData
        },{
          label: 'Meat',
          data: meatData
        },{
          label: 'Juice',
          data: juiceData
         }]
    }
```

Any hint on a solution with Chart.js?

Comment: It's difficult to tell from your post what the shape of your objects are. You call them objects but `bread=>5, juice=>3` make them look like arrays. Give me a better idea of the data structure. For example: If I wanted to see the bread number from `object1`, what would I echo?

Comment: sure thing, I have edited with the class of my object

Comment: How do you even know whether you have 3 or 300 datasets?  In your example there are 'bread', 'meat' and 'juice' but nothing in your objects structure suggests any limitation to the type of food. Are there only ever those 3 possibilities?

Comment: it will be in the order of 50 to 100

Comment: but of course I don't know in advance

Comment: So you're going to have 50 to 100 plots on the same chart?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120608/discussion-between-user299791-and-beetlejuice).